# Shiny inside the new learnr package does not work

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, r-markdown

The documentation of the new learnr-package [states](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/index.html#shiny_components) that

> it’s also possible to add other forms of interactivity using Shiny (e.g. for teaching a statistical concept interactively).

I tried it with the provided example but I could not manage it. The slider does appear but not the plot. I used:

````
---
title: "Tutorial"
output:
    learnr::tutorial:
            progressive: true
            allow_skip: true
runtime: shiny_prerendered
tutorial: 
    version: 0.1
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(learnr)
library(checkr)
library(shiny)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(exercise.checker = checkr::checkr_tutor)
```
````

The example did work with

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
runtime: shiny
---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked the problem down: It was completely my own fault. I used the same name for the input variable in another R chunk with shiny code.

I did not get any error message, the output just did not show up.